# Navigating effectively in scrollView

Tags: scrollview, android

In my android application I have a background and at the bottom a horizontal scrollView. In this scrollView I have 4 buttons each one representing a separate activity plus 2 more which are arrows for scrolling left and right, if the user scrolls right then 4 different buttons will populate the scrollview. In my Current VM, it works correctly but if I switch to one with a larger screen then instead of 4 buttons I have 5 or even 5 and a half, at it scrolls much less. My question is how can I always have 6 buttons in my scrollView (4 activity buttons and the extra two arrows for navigating in the scrollView) independently of the size and the density if the screen. This is the xml I've written so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fonto1" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/aristerovelos2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/aristerovelos1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ellinika"
            android:background="@drawable/aristerovelos3"
            android:src="@drawable/aristerovelos3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ispanika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/agglika"
            android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/aristerovelos2"
            android:background="@drawable/ispanika"
            android:src="@drawable/ispanika" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/italika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/agglika"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ispanika"
            android:background="@drawable/italika"
            android:src="@drawable/italika" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rosika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/agglika"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/italika"
            android:background="@drawable/rosika"
            android:src="@drawable/rosika" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deksivelos2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/aristerovelos1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rosika"
            android:background="@drawable/deksivelos3"
            android:src="@drawable/deksivelos3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/aristerovelos1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/aristerovelos3"
            android:src="@drawable/aristerovelos3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/galika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/agglika"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/agglika"
            android:background="@drawable/agglika"
            android:src="@drawable/gallika" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/germanika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/galika"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/galika"
            android:background="@drawable/germanika"
            android:src="@drawable/germanika" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ellinika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/germanika"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/germanika"
            android:background="@drawable/ellinika"
            android:src="@drawable/ellinika" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/agglika"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/aristerovelos1"
            android:background="@drawable/agglika"
            android:src="@drawable/agglika" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deksivelos1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/aristerovelos2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ellinika"
            android:background="@drawable/deksivelos3"
            android:src="@drawable/deksivelos3" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/grammi" />
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? post your code so that some can help you.

Comment: You have to update the width of the buttons in code to 1/4 of the screen size.

Comment: what happens if this for example in a tablet? the button i guess will be pretty stressed

Comment: This UI seems better suited for ViewPager, from the support library. You could give the ViewPager multiple LinearLayout children, each with four buttons in it. Then put your two arrow buttons outside the ViewPager on either side. Then each of your LinearLayout children can have a width of match_parent and gravity:center so the buttons don't get stretched on a tablet.

Comment: Well that that is really specific thanks I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: @Tenfour04 hey thank you very much!! exactly the result I was hopping to get. Another problem has risen though when I have a low density screen the images won't fit and as a result the last one get really small. Do you know how I can set them all to be a little smaller so that they fit in an acceptable manner?

Comment: Hmm, maybe post a new question and show your code. It depends on how you're implementing it.

Comment: I've fixed it thank you so much. Pitty you won't get upvoted..You really helped me